# "Understand that..." in Japanese

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses

I'm wondering about this specific piece of grammar. I think you use "wakaru", but what do you use it with?
Do you use a particle, like "to" or maybe some other construction?

For example, if you wanted to say: "She understood that time was running out.", what would you say/write?

-- Thank you! ^^
(It says to not post this as a comment and somehow the comment button doesn't even work for me... oh well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say:

> もう(あまり)時間がないとわかった。(She realized that...)
>   or
>   もう(あまり)時間がないとわかっていた。(She was aware that...)

using the quotative particle と. Or:

> もう(あまり)時間がないことがわかった。(She realized...)
>   or
>   もう(あまり)時間がないことがわかっていた。(She was aware that...)

using the case particle が: 「～～が+わかる」

If you use 理解する, add the particle を:

> もう(あまり)時間がないことを理解した。(She realized...)
>   or
>   もう(あまり)時間がないことを理解していた。(She was aware...)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably say something like :

> 時間が尽きてることってわかっていた

But I am not a native speaker so this may not be the best one...

Comment: It means "She understands that it means time runs out".

Comment: @user4092 right on target.

Comment: Actually I overlooked て against 尽きてる and the tense of the verb, so it should have been "she understood that it meant time has run out".

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not a native speaker but I would write the following

> 彼女は時間が少ししか残ってなかったことが理解していました。
>
> The girl understood (was aware) that there was little time left.

Comment: Did you mean to write を理解していました？

Comment: @DariusJahandarie I'm never sure. If you are confident that を is correct. Please edit the answer. I've been speaking it for a long time but I still have trouble in this area.

Comment: 「彼女は時間が少ししか残っていないことを理解していました。」ならよいと思います。